# How to format date-time for RFC2445 in PHP

Tags: php, calendar, rfc2445

I am working on Google Calendar API using its PHP library and I need to set a recurring event for which I have to create a RRule string which should be of following format:

```
RRULE:FREQ=WEEKLY;UNTIL=20110701T170000Z
```

I am unable to create the date in above format. I literally tried all methods like:

```
date('YmdHis');
date(DATE_RFC2822);
date('c');
```

But Google doesn't accept any of above formats. I need to make it like: 20110701T170000Z. Can anybody help me on this?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is your date format:

```
date('Ymd\THis\Z')
```

becomes

```
20150429T154315Z
```

Look at the examples here: http://php.net/manual/de/function.date.php

Answer (score 2):

Are you able to concatenate two strings together and form the required datetime string in RFC2822?

```
<?php
    $ymd = date('Ymd');
    $hms = date('His');
    echo $ymd."T".$hms."Z"; //Will output YYYYMMDDTHHMMSSZ
?>
```

Let me know if this works! :)

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
date('Ymd\THis\Z', $timestamp);
```

or

```
date('Ymd\THis\Z');
```

if you want the current timestamp